# import ".lib" file orcad LM22670

Tags: library, orcad, pspice, import

I'm trying to import a step down voltage regulator from texas instrument into orcad capture.

> LM22670-ADJ Unencrypted PSpice Transient Model
>
> Pspice model available at texas instruments (was unavailable to have more than 2 links)

I have tried to follow a [guide](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/TND6045-D.PDF), but after completing all the steps, I'm not available to place the hole component, only parts of it (see image). 
[image]

It seems like orcad doesn't look at the imported "lib" file, like one component, instead it exports it as "LM22670" is a library itself, with the other SUBCKT and Diode as the part of a library called "LM22670".
Maybe the guide i'm using isn't applicable on these kinds of components, how ever I would gladly receive any help, which helps me successfully import this model. Thank you.

Comment: Could you add a bit more information to your question to clarify what is (not) happening more specifically. IE "I'm not available to place the hole component, only parts of it (see image)." Your screen shot shows its a 1 Part per Package...

Comment: I have now updated the problem, i hope it's easier to understand what i mean now.

Comment: I am sorry, I am still not sure what your question is. Can you place the symbol in Capture? If you are having trouble simulating; have you added the library to your P-Spice configuration (Menu -> P-Spice -> Edit Simulation Profile -> Configuration Files Tab -> Category : Library)?

Comment: This link seems to be pretty comprehensive, although I have not followed it myself.  https://4cesolutions.wordpress.com/2012/07/07/steps-to-import-a-spice-model-into-orcad-16-5-from-dl-text-through-sim-result-2/